# Deserialization Unity and c#, list into another list

Tags: c#, android, css, json, serialization

sorry for my english, so well, I’m trying to deserialize a json file on UNITY and C#, 
Everything works fine when I got a list of objects (int, string, float, bool inside) no problema on that, 
[JSON BASIC STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjWen.jpg)

But when I got a list whose elements has another list inside comes problem, I mean list inside another list
[json second structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BZsW.jpg)

My c# code, I load json file, (I got this config because it works on Android and unity editor)

```css
 public void loadjsonfile(string jsonfilename)
 {
  TextAsset file = Resources.Load(jsonfilename) as TextAsset;
  jsonData = file.ToString ();
 }
 public List<club> findClubsIn(string jsonFilename, string leagueName)
 {
  List<club> clubFound = new List<club>();
  if(jsonFilename.Equals("european_club"))
  {
   loadjsonfile (jsonFilename);
   europeanClub uefaclubs = JsonUtility.FromJson<europeanClub> (jsonData);
   List<club> clubList = uefaclubs.europeanClubs;
   foreach (club cl in clubList)
   {
    if (cl.league.Equals (leagueName))
    {
     //Debug.Log (cl.name);
     clubFound.Add (cl);
    }
   }
   return clubFound;
  }
  clubFound.Clear ();
  return clubFound;
 }
```

Now, in the same class I got this

```css
[System.Serializable]
public class cab
{
 public float domestic_league;
 public float domestic_cup;
 public float domestic_s_cup;
 public float euro_champ_cup;
 public float euro_league;
 public float euro_s_cup;
 public float inter_club_champ;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class kits
{
 public string h_m_color;
 public string h_s_color;
 public string a_m_color;
 public string a_s_color;
 public string kit_sponsor;
 public string kit_supplier;
 public string sp_contract;
 public string supp_contract;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class transf
{
 public float transfer_budget;
 public float wage_budget;
 public float foreign_p_bias;
 public float transfer_activity;
 public bool only_national;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class fac
{
 public string stadium;
 public float stadium_cap;
 public string training_facilities;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class club
{
 public int club_id;
 public string sprite_id;
 public string name;
 public string confederation;
 public string nation;
 public string league;
 public float overall;
 public float international_rep;
 public float domestic_rep;
 public string financial_state;
 public float youth_policy;
 public string second_team;
 public float market_value;
 public string manager;
 public float squad_size;
 public string continental_comp;
 public string continental_s_cup;
 public List<fac> facilities;
 public List<transf> transfers;
 public List<kits> kit;
 public List<cab> cabinet;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class europeanClub
{
 public List<club> europeanClubs;
}
```

But when I try to do this problems comes, I really don’t know what I’m doing bad, hope you can help, thanks in advance.

```css
JsonDataHandler data = new JsonDataHandler ();
   List<club> clubsFound = data.findClubsIn ("european_club","Premier League");
   List<fac> fac = new List<fac> ();
   foreach(club cl in clubsFound)
   {
    fac.Add (cl.facilities);
   }
   foreach(fac fs in fac)
   {
    Debug.Log (fs.stadium);
   }
```

Error
Assets/Scripts/scrollClub.cs(42,9): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(fac)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"cl.facilities" is List. Therefore it shows error when you add it to the list. You may change it to "fac.AddRange(cl.facilities)" to append to the list instead.